# Wordpress - How to specify an ID in custom Visual Composer element

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, visual-composer

I'm current building a website for a non-profit, and am using an older edition of the Wordpress theme, [Savior](https://creativemarket.com/ThemeBuddies/8900-Savior-Charity-Theme).

There is a custom post type of [Donations](https://support.stylemixthemes.com/manuals/savior/#content7), and it allows the admin to set up different "Causes", each of which is a post with a specific ID.

By default, the theme has a custom Visual Composer element (Screenshot 1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmhTu.png) that allows you to feature the most recent "Cause"; the only customization option you have is for the Title of the VC element.

**I'm trying to update this custom VC element so that the admin can specify the exact ID for the "Cause" they would like to feature on a page/post vs. only showing the latest "Cause."**

I've adjusted the VC mapping for the *cause.php* template where commented below:

```
<?php

class STM_VC_Causes {

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'integrateWithVC' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'stm_causes', array( $this, 'render' ) );
    }

    public function integrateWithVC() {
        if ( function_exists( 'vc_map' ) ) {
            vc_map( array(
                'name'        => __( 'Causes', STM_DOMAIN ),
                'base'        => 'stm_causes',
                'category'    => __( 'STM', STM_DOMAIN ),
                'params'      => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'textfield',
                        'class' => '',
                        'heading' => __( 'Title', STM_DOMAIN ),
                        'param_name' => 'title',
                        'value' => __( 'Our Causes', STM_DOMAIN )
                    ),

                    /** ========================================
                     * Qing Custom 8-6-2018
                     * Allow admin to select Cause to feature
                    ======================================== **/

                    array(
                        'type' => 'textfield',
                        'class' => '',
                        'heading' => __( 'Cause ID', STM_DOMAIN ),
                        'param_name' => 'id',
                        'value' => __( '', STM_DOMAIN )
                    )
                )
            ) );
        }
    }


    public function render( $atts, $content = null ) {

        /** ========================================
         * Qing Custom 8-6-2018
         * Display selected Cause ID
        ======================================== **/

        $title = '';
        $id = '';

        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'title'       => '',
            'id'       => ''
        ), $atts ) );

        $fea_cause = $atts['id'];
        $donations = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'donation', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post__in' => $fea_cause ) );

        $output = '';
        $output .= '<ul class="donation-grid first clearfix">';
        while ( $donations->have_posts() ) {

            $donations->the_post();
            $target_amount         = ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_target', true ) == '' ) ? 0 : get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_target', true );
            $raised_amount         = ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_raised', true ) == '' ) ? 0 : get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_raised', true );
            $currency              = ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_currency', true ) == '' ) ? '$' : get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_currency', true );
            $donors                = ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_donors', true ) == '' ) ? 0 : get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'donation_donors', true );
            $target_amount_percent = ( $raised_amount / $target_amount ) * 100;

            $output .= '<li id="post-' . get_the_ID() . '" class="' . implode( ' ', get_post_class() ) . '">';
            $output .= '<div class="donation-thumbnail">';
            $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), 'thumb-150x150' );
            }
            $output .= '</a>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="donation-content">';
            $output .= '<h4><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>';
            $output .= '<div class="progress_bar"><span style="width: ' . $target_amount_percent . '%;"></span></div>';
            $output .= '<div class="donation-stat">';
            $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-child"></i> ' . __( 'Raised', STM_DOMAIN ) . '<br/>' . $currency . $raised_amount . '</span>';
            $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-users"></i> ' . __( 'Donors', STM_DOMAIN ) . '<br/>' . $donors . '</span>';
            $output .= '<span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> ' . __( 'Goal', STM_DOMAIN ) . '<br/>' . $currency . $target_amount . '</span>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="donate_now">';
            $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="button cause_donate_btn">' . __( 'DONATE NOW', STM_DOMAIN ) . '</a>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>';
        wp_reset_query();

        return $output;
    }

}

if( defined( 'WPB_VC_VERSION' ) ){
    new STM_VC_Causes();
}

?>
```

The custom VC element is showing up correctly for me on the admin backend side of the site (Screenshot 2 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKCgs.png), but I cannot figure out how to get the admin-inputted ID to show up on the frontend - no matter what, it still shows the most recent "Cause." Screenshot 3 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Qw4.png) is simply an example screenshot of what the individual "Cause" looks like when a page with the custom VC element is pushed live.

I've contacted the support team for the theme, but they only suggested this [Post Types Order WP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/), which only allows you to change the displayed "Cause" across the entire site, instead of allowing you to specify it in a page-by-page/post-by-post basis. I've also scoured Google/StackOverflow and tried various queries in the WP Codex, building out a custom shortcode (the custom VC element itself is a custom shortcode: `[stm_causes]`), but it just displays the most recent "Cause."

***Edit 8/7/18:***

I've made several edits to the causes.php template within the Savior theme, but for some reason, the updated `WP_Query` loop ended up not pulling in any data (Screenshot 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLibO.png ).

The only exception is if I omit any ID in the VC editor backend; If I don't enter an ID, it defaults to the most recent Cause. However, if I enter any ID, even if it's the same ID as the most recent post, nothing shows up...

Any idea what could be wrong with my logic?

Thank you!

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

`render` function Fixed!

```
$fea_cause = $atts['id'];    
$donations = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'donation', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post__in' => array($fea_cause )));
```

Huge props to [Nilesh Sanura](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/148097/nilesh-sanura) for his help!